# Tinymce error : invalid UTF-8 byte sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, activeadmin

Recently I added Tinymce to my active-admin interface. So that all text areas would have that editor.
I followed these 2 years old [guidlines](http://code.davemorro.com/post/7919233521/hacking-activeadmin-adding-a-javascript-text-editor)

I did everything like there, then after server restart I get this error:

```
C:/Users/Edza/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/darbs/app/assets/javascripts/tiny_mce/plugins/spellchecker/editor_plugin.js has a invalid UTF-8 byte sequence
```

I searched for other solution, found this: https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails/issues/118

There is said that I need to install newest version off Tinymce by addin this in `gem " tinymce-rails", "~> 3.5.9.pre2"` in Gemfile. I ran `bundle install`, restarted the server but still got the same error.

**Q** Should I look for recent guide to add tinymce in active admin? Because 2 years old can be too old ? Or there is other problem over there?

**Update**

```
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in read_unicode'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:13:in `tap'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:13:in `block in read_unicode'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:12:in `open'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:12:in `open'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/utils.rb:12:in `read_unicode'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/context.rb:184:in `evaluate'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `new'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:270:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:248:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `new'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:249:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:270:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:248:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:38:in `init_with'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/asset.rb:24:in `from_hash'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:15:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:78:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:177:in `[]'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:126:in `asset_for'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:27:in `block in javascript_include_tag'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:26:in `collect'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:26:in `javascript_include_tag'
app/views/home/index.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_home_index_html_erb__950850484_38370048'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__214337580__process_action__565932412__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__922026778__call__493736183__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
eventmachine-1.0.3-x86 (mingw32) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine-1.0.3-x86 (mingw32) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What is the stacktrace of the error you get?

Comment: @poseid You mean full trace ?

Comment: yes, it is important to understand what gems/versions are involved.

Comment: @poseid I added update with full ap trace.

Comment: At this moment to get work that I deleted  editor_plugin editor_plugin_src files. Now It works for moment.